# In PowerShell, list of Git branches loses its array structure when saved to a variable

Tags: powershell

I've got a PowerShell script that lists the local and remote branches of a Git repository and allows the user to select one, before going on to act on that branch. The key section:

```
git fetch
$branch = (
    git branch --all |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "->" } |
    ForEach-Object {$_.substring(2)} |
    Out-GridView -Title "$project`: Select a branch to build" -OutputMode Single
)
if ($branch -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "No branch selected, ending"
}
else {
    Write-Output "Branch $branch selected"
[...]
```

This works well. The grid presents a list similar to the following

```
chris/branch1
main
remotes/origin/main
remotes/origin/terry/fix1
remotes/origin/terry/feature
```

Now I want to omit remote branches for which there is already a local branch. (Yes, I'm assuming that local branches share the name of the remote branches that they're tracking.) So I tried this:

```
$branches = (
    git branch --all |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "->" } |
    ForEach-Object {$_.substring(2)}
)
$branch = (
    Where-Object -InputObject $branches { ($_ -notmatch "^remotes/origin/") -or ($branches -notcontains ($_ -replace "^remotes/origin/", "")) } |
    Out-GridView -Title "$project`: Select a branch to build" -OutputMode Single
)
if ($branch -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "No branch selected, ending"
}
else {
    Write-Output "Branch $branch selected"
[...]
```

Now the grid shows me all the branches on a single line:

```
{chris/branch1, main, remotes/origin/main, remotes/origin/terry/fix1, remotes/origin/terry/feature}
```

Adding `Write-Output "$branches"` after the statement where `$branches` is assigned gives this in the console:

```
chris/branch1
main
remotes/origin/main
remotes/origin/terry/fix1
remotes/origin/terry/feature
```

so the items are still separate from each other at that point.

In case the filtering Where-Object statement was causing the problem, I removed it, and I still got all the branches catenated together in a single grid item. The code at this point:

```
git fetch
$branches = (
    git branch --all |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "->" } |
    ForEach-Object {$_.substring(2)}
)
Write-Output $branches
$branch = (
    Out-GridView -InputObject $branches -Title "$project`: Select a branch to build" -OutputMode Single
)
if ($branch -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "No branch selected, ending"
}
else {
    Write-Output "Branch $branch selected"
[...]
```

Why is my array, which was originally displayed in the grid on multiple lines, displayed in catenated format after I added the intermediate assignment to $branches?

Comment: Change `Where-Object -InputObject $branches ...` to `$branches |Where-Object ...`

Comment: Oh, beautiful, thank you! I didn't know you could do that. (I'm a PowerShell newbie, which may have been obvious just from that.) But, then, what's -InputObject for, and how is it different?